# AWS Mobile Hub Device token APNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications

Got the certificate and provisioning and the app to download. But it doesn't work because it mentions device token invalid when I checked the logs. How do I get the correct device token ? I just want to test out push notification on AWS Mobile. I read somewhere it changes everytime you run the app? Running iOS 9, xCode 7.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Marin,

The most likely scenario for the invalid token using Mobile Hub is that you are using a Development Provisioning profile on the device. When you launch an app using a developer provisioning profile, Apple will issue a push token for Development (Sandbox) only. When you enabled Push Notification in your Mobile Hub project, Mobile Hub creates a Production SNS Platform Application which is expecting a Production push token issued by Apple.

To resolve this, just create an "Ad Hoc provisioning profile" for your App ID (Ad Hoc profile uses the production push endpoint) and then re-launch the app. You should then receive a new production token from Apple and then publish to the SNS Endpoint associated with that new token.

Comment: Thank you. I tried using an Ad Hoc Provisioning profile.  However I'm getting  an error mentioning "Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 619"   I have changed the bundle id from the default com.amazon.MySampleApp to mine.  I did change the code signing to distribution but no luck. I then reverted code signing to automatic but no luck running the program. It works only if I use my email under team. However no push...

Comment: Instead of troubleshooting the environment, there's one more suggestion. First, download the sample app again from Mobile Hub to start fresh. 1. Log into the SNS Console and create an Apple Development Platform Application using the same hybrid Push Cert used with MH. 2. In your app project, find the platform application ARN in the info.plist and replace the production ARN with the newly created Developer platform application ARN. You can then continue using the dev provisioning profile and it should just work in debug. Push only works on physical devices, for now.

Comment: Hello Dennis, thank you for your answer, I was able to resolve it your way 2 days ago and I can vouch that it works - Thank you.